# Is it necessarily the case that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \text{gap } P_{k} = 0$ if $\{P_{k}\}$ is an Archimidean sequence of partitions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

Is it necessarily the case that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \text{gap } P_{k} = 0$ if $\{P_{k}\}$ is an Archimidean sequence of partitions?

I know that by the definition of an Archmedean sequence of partitions, we have

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}[U(f, P_{k}) - L(f, P_{k})] = 0. $$

Also by Archimedean Riemann, we get

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} L(f, P_{k}) = \int_{I} f = \lim_{k\to\infty} U(f,P_{k}). $$

So it's nowhere stated, but I can't come up with a counterexample. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if $f$ is constant on some non-degenerate interval?

Comment: If $f$ is constant on a non-degenerate interval, we get $U(f, P_{k}) = c \cdot \text{vol } J$ and $L(f, P_{k}) = c \cdot \text{vol } J$. I see that the limit goes to $0$ then, but do I need to provide an example of a sequence $P_{k}$?

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting "gap"; I took it to mean the length of the largest subinterval of the partition. (Then take each $P_k$ to be the entire interval.)